# input text field is not same with its contained icons

Tags: html, forms, webforms, frontend, web-frontend

Here is the input field of my form:
[image]

its functioning well but not displaying correctly

Here is my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="datepicker">Expire Date</label>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group date-select-with-expire-option">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text"> <i
                        class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control date-input"
                    name="SelectedDate" placeholder="Select date" />
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <div class="input-group-text">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input expire-option"
                                name="DateNeverExpires" id="never-expired"> <label
                                class="custom-control-label" for="never-expired"> Never
                                expires </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here the same code in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Raakh5/pvf4y235/5/) working fine. but not on my page

I don't know where I am making mistake.

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: Can you share CSS as well and make this to run in code snippet.

Comment: @MuhammadHuzaifa I added jsFiddle in my question but really its strange that in JSFiddle working fine but not on my page

Comment: something is over-riding the styling of bootstrap classes. check it out, if you're using custom CSS.

Comment: @MuhammadHuzaifa. Thanks for pin pointing. I found one of my css is conflicting. I have updated jsFiddle link. Please check and let me know how can I fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`margin` property is adding margin at the top, removing it will solve your** **problem.**

```html
input[type=text], select {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;

  /* margin: 8px 0; */ # Remove this

  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Check at [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dev_hope/1run2c8z/)

Comment: Now the problem with deleting margin is that it effected lot of other forms. How can I not use this css for this specific input field and rest remain as usual

Comment: You can add an extra class to this form and override CSS using that class.

Answer (score 1):

```
input[type=text], select {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 6px 20px;       /* Changed padding to 6px */
    margin: 0px 0px;         /* Changed margin to 0px */
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=submit] {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 6px 20px;       /* Changed padding to 6px */
    margin: 0px 0px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.far {
    line-height: 1.5!important; /* Took the class .far and force-changed the 
                                   property with !important */
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to help the original poster understand why this will work for them. This also helps later readers coming to this post, they will also understand if this answer applies to their problem.

Comment: Sorry @PeterS, i'm new to this and don't know how to add that bold title like in the other answer. I added comments in the code itself to explain. Thanks for your tip!

Comment: No problem, please take a look at other answers from seasoned contributors, you will see how they answer things, there's a bit of prose followed by some code (just enough to understand). Just code sometimes has no general context and may be outdated if the framework is updated. The prose helps this situation.